# Azure dashboard deployment using ARM template issue

Tags: azure, dashboard, azure-rm-template

Trying to deploy Azure Dashboard through ARM template and getting an issue after deployment (see screenshot below).

The following document was used to construct template: [Azure Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically)

ARM template looks like:

```
      "log-analytics-workspace-id": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourcegroups/rg-ProjectX-dev-infra",
      "allowedValues": [
            "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourcegroups/rg-ProjectX-dev-infra"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The resource ID for an existing Log Analytics workspace."
      }
    }
    "variables": {
      "la-name": "[concat('la', '-', parameters('base-name'), '-', 'workspace')]",
        
        {
        "name": "Scope",
        "value": {
          "resourceIds": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Operationalinsights/workspaces', parameters('log-analytics-workspace-id'), variables('la-name'))]"
          },
       "isOptional": true
        }
```

**resourceIds** value defined like:

```
            "name": "Scope",
            "value": {
                "resourceIds": "[parameters('log-analytics-workspace-id')]"
              },
              "isOptional": true
            },
```

...and paremeter defined **log-analytics-workspace-id**:

```
      "log-analytics-workspace-id": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourcegroups/rg-ProjectX-dev-infra/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/la-ProjectX-dev-workspace",
      "allowedValues": [
            "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourcegroups/rg-ProjectX-dev-infra/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/la-ProjectX-dev-workspace"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The resource ID for an existing Log Analytics workspace."
      }
  }
```

Azure Dashboard has deployed successfully, however, the dashboard **is not operational** yet:

[Azure dashboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEjZV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed an issue by combining the value in array:

```
{
  "name": "Scope",
  "value": {
     "resourceIds": [
     "[parameters('log-analytics-workspace-id')]"
     ]
  }
},
```